# How to properly use static methods?

Tags: python, static, static-methods

Coming from C++ I don't get static member methods working.

```
class Color():
    def __init__(self):
        print ("red")

    @staticmethod
    def cl(val):
        return float(val / Color.colorConstant)

    red = (Color.cl(1.0), 0.0, 0.0)
    green = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    blue = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    purple = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    colorConstant = 255
```

I get the error: `name 'Color' is not defined # on line 9`

```
red = (Color.cl(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Should this code normally work? I want to call a static method when defining member attribute.

Comment: Is your code correctly indented in your post?

Comment: Is the error on this line `red = (Color.cl(1.0), 0.0, 0.0)` or on this line `return float(val / Color.colorConstant)`?

Comment: I edited now the indentation. @MaximeLorant. it's on the line with ''red = (Color.cl(1.0), 0.0, 0.0)''

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 16:33:56) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] (MAYA)

Comment: Your indentation is faulty if your intent is to declare it outside of the class, otherwise you can't refer to the class within itself like you're doing.

Comment: When i run your code i get a different error: `AttributeError: class Color has no attribute 'colorConstant'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do won’t work. The reason for this is the way Python resolves names and when the type you are definining is assigned to a name. In your example, you are definining the type with the name `Color`. During the definition, i.e. everything within `class`, the name `Color` hasn’t been set yet, so Python cannot resolve the name. That’s why accessing `Color` from within its own definition won’t work.

You can think of this process like this:

```
class <SomeAnonymousTypeName>:
    method and member definitions
Color = <SomeAnonymousTypeName>
```

So only *after* the definition, the type name is assigned.

Instead, you will have to make the definition work without having to reference the type. You could also dynamically add the constants *after* defining the type:

```
class Color:
    …

Color.red = …
Color.green = …
```

Comment: But when i create a static member function, it should be available already?

Comment: Not in Python. The `staticmethod` decorator will just adjust the method you are definining in some way to make it callable without an object. But there are no “real” static members like you know from C. It’s still a dynamic language which is evaluated at run-time.

Comment: Allright, that solves my problem, any other suggestions creating a predefined color class?